# ADT-like polymorphism in Java (without altering class)

Tags: java, haskell, algebraic-data-types

In *Haskell* I can define following data type:

```
data Tree = Empty
      | Leaf Int
      | Node Tree Tree
```

and then write polymorphic function like this:

```
depth :: Tree -> Int
depth Empty = 0
depth (Leaf n) = 1
depth (Node l r) = 1 + max (depth l) (depth r)
```

In *Java* I can emulate algebraic data types with interfaces:

```
interface Tree {}
class Empty implements Tree {}
class Leaf implements Tree { int n; }
class Node implements Tree { Tree l; Tree r; }
```

But if I try to use Haskell-like polymorphism, I get an error:

```
int depth(Empty node) {
    return 0;
}
int depth(Leaf node) {
    return 1;
}
int depth(Node node) {
    return 1 + Math.max(depth(node.l), depth(node.r));   // ERROR: Cannot resolve method 'depth(Tree)'
}
```

Correct way to overcome this is to **put method** `depth()` **to each class**. But what if I **don't want** to put it there? For example, method `depth()` may be not directly related to `Tree` and adding it to class would break business logic. Or, even worse, `Tree` may be written in 3rd party library that I don't have access to. In this case, what is the **simplest way** to implement **ADT-like polymorpism**?

Just in case, for the moment I'm using following syntax, which is obviously ill-favored:

```
int depth(Tree tree) {
    if (tree instanceof Empty) depth((Empty)tree)
    if (tree instanceof Leaf) depth((Leaf)tree);
    if (tree instanceof Node) depth((Node)tree); 
    else throw new RuntimeException("Don't know how to find depth of " + tree.getClass());
}
```

Comment: nothing wrong with your current ill-favored solution. it's no worse than the Haskell solution

Comment: @irreputable: The difference is that in Haskell you have a fixed set of cases known statically and checked by the compiler, so there's no need for a default case or possibility of creating a runtime error by giving it something it doesn't expect. Giving up that many benefits of static typing is most certainly worse.

Comment: Would subtype polymorphism not be simpler? i.e. create an interface such as TreeInterface, with a method depth, then have classes Empty, Leaf and Node implementing it?

Comment: @MrLore: if I understand your suggestion correctly, what is the difference between `TreeInterface` and my `Tree` which is already an interface for `Empty`, `Leaf` and `Node`?

Comment: @ffriend My bad, I missed the part where you said you didn't want to add a depth() method to the classes so that renders it moot. (Edit: deleted as I just realised you couldn't switch that kind of Object.)

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Most answers suggest some kind of Visitor pattern and thus are equally valuable, so I just accepted one that got highest number of upvotes.

Comment: Note, the Haskell version of `depth` is not a polymorphic function. `Tree` is a sum type with different constructors, but each constructor produces the same thing - an object of type `Tree`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this.

Sorry, my Java is very rusty. If, unlike me, you can remember the syntax, you could use Java generics to refine `Object` to `Integer` or whatever class the method you're writing needs. But you can't (can you?) return primitive types, sorry.

```
interface TreeFolder {
    Object onEmpty();
    Object onLeaf (int n);
    Object onNode (Tree l, Tree r);
}

interface Tree {
    Object fold (TreeFolder f);
}

class Empty implements Tree {
    Object fold (TreeFolder f) {
        return f.onEmpty();
    }
}

class Leaf implements Tree {
    private int n;
    Object fold (TreeFolder f) {
        return f.onLeaf (n);
    }
}

class Node implements Tree {
    private Tree l, r;
    Object fold (TreeFolder f) {
        return f.onNode (l, r);
    }
}

// meanwhile, in a class in another package far far away...
Object depth (Tree tree) {
    return tree.fold (new TreeFolder() {
        Object onEmpty() { return new Integer(0); }
        Object onLeaf (int n) { return new Integer(n); }
        Object onNode (Tree l, Tree r) {
            Integer ll = (Integer) l.fold (this);
            Integer rr = (Integer) r.fold (this);
            return new Integer (ll.intValue() + rr.intValue());
        }
    });
}
```

Note that in `depth()` I have to manually recurse (call `fold()`) on the `Tree` parameters. You could instead choose to recurse on them upfront in `Node.fold()` (and change `TreeFolder` accordingly), but then you *have* to recurse --- you can't choose to recurse only into the left subtree, should you wish to. (In Haskell we don't have to make that trade-off thanks to laziness.)

Comment: You can return primitives in Java.

Comment: Assuming the value can always be cast as that primitive type, sure.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a rough sketch of one way you could approach this, in a general and extensible way. It won't work directly in all cases, but might help you get started.

First, some starting assumptions:

1. We don't want anything specific to `depth` added to the `Tree` classes.
2. We don't want to lose the benefits of static types.

The key point is to realize that the Haskell code you want to recreate here is not the `Tree` type itself, but rather the *pattern match* on it. As such, we'll start by making "pattern matching on a tree" a first class (ha, ha) entity in its own right. Using C#-ish pseudocode, because I haven't used Java in years:

```
interface MatchTree<R> 
{
    R matchEmpty(Empty empty);
    R matchLeaf(Leaf leaf);
    R matchNode(Node node);
}
```

To use this reified pattern match, we need an appropriate method on `Tree`:

```
interface Tree
{
    R patternMatch<R>(MatchTree<R> patterns);
}
```

Each individual `Tree` subtype can then implement the function by calling the appropriate `MatchTree` method with itself as an argument.

The equivalent Haskell would be something like this:

```
data MatchTree r = MatchTree { matchEmpty :: r
                             , matchLeaf :: Int -> r
                             , matchNode :: Tree -> Tree -> r
                             }
```

...which can be easily seen to correspond directly with a case expression:

```
match tree z fl fn = case tree of
                       Empty -> z
                       Leaf x -> fl i
                       Node lt rt -> fn lt rt
```

This style of reified pattern match is known in OOP circles as the "visitor pattern", incidentally.

Answer (score 7):

> For example, method depth() may be not directly related to Tree and
>   adding it to class would break business logic. Or, even worse, Tree
>   may be written in 3rd party library that I don't have access to. In
>   this case, what is the simplest way to implement ADT-like polymorpism?

In this case - I'd suggest you to use design pattern **[Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)**. It allows you to **separate representation of data and logic of processing**, even more - it allows you to implement different processing strategies.

Answer (score 5):

@stemm is correct that the visitor pattern is well suited for this problem. I would however also recommend you to look at a modified version of the well known visitor pattern. A blogger invented this [church encoding pattern](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/structural-pattern-matching-in-java/). This pattern is more dense and have a much more functional style than the visitor pattern.

Comment: Wow, this is really something crazy. But what if we have much more type constructors, e.g. like in case of abstract syntax tree, where we have, say, 20-30 subtypes. In this case should we put all 20-30 types into `match()` method definition?

Comment: Yea, if you think of it as pattern matching it is quite natural.

Answer (score 2):

edit: This is the answer you didn't want (put `depth()` in the `Tree` interface), but I think it deserves a full analysis anyway.

---

More broadly, this is the issue of implementing *sum types using
classes*. There is a pretty common way to have sum types in object
oriented languages. Namely, the *interpreter pattern*.

```
interface Tree { int depth(); }

class Empty implements Tree { int depth(){ return 0; }

class Leaf implements Tree {
  int n;
  int depth(){ return 1; }
}

class Node implements Tree {
  Tree l; Tree r;
  int depth(){ return max(depth(l), depth(r)); }
}
```

Let's compare this to the haskell approach! It's quite clear that the
author of the classes can have arbitrarily many types (`Empty`, `Leaf`,
`Node`) and methods (`depth()`, `numLeafs()`). However, what about a
external code that wants to extend this tree library?

Using algebraic data types in haskell, an external code base can add
tree functions of type `:: Tree -> a` if the library exposes `Tree(..)`
(The type itself and all three constructors). However, one cannot add a
new constructor to `Tree`, like this:

```
-- Code far far away can't do this in haskell
data Tree = ...
          | ...
          | Node3 Tree Tree Tree
```

But in java when using the interpreter pattern, it is the opposite.
One cannot add a new method to the `Tree` interface, but one can just
add a new constructor like this:

```
-- Code far far away *can* do this in java
class Node3 implements Tree {
  Tree l; Tree mid; Tree r;
  int depth(){ ... }
}
```

---

In conclusion, this design pattern works great if:

- Others want to add terms to the algebraic data structure.
- You desire full type safety

yet it is somewhat unsatisfactory because:

- Others can't add reducer functions like `numNodes()`
- It feels contrived that a method on Trees have to be put once in
  every class. We would prefer pattern matching a tree
  once per method, instead we are doing it in sort of a
  transposed way.

Comment: See also: [the Expression Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). :]

Comment: @C.A.McCann Oh. Didn't know this issue had it's own name. Do you know of any language that have solved expression problem?

Comment: In a way it's not something that can simply be "solved" in general, because if you add both a new case and a new operation, you need to define the latter on the former, and there's no obvious choice of where that definition belongs. The two kinds of extensibility are never going to be truly orthogonal because of that. On the flip side, most languages provide some sort of tools to help mitigate the problem. The references in the Wikipedia article will point you toward more information. Also, the term was coined by Wadler, whose other work you're probably very familiar with. :]

Comment: Ok, that's the disappointing answer I expected. Anyway, I'm very glad that you confirmed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any pleasant solution.

I hope this may help you.

```
interface Tree {
}

class Empty implements Tree {
}

class Leaf implements Tree {
    int n;
}

class Node implements Tree {
    Tree l;
    Tree r;
}

class Test{

    public static void main (String args[]){

        Test p = new Test();
        Empty e = new Empty();      
        System.out.println(p.depth(e));
        Leaf t = new Leaf();
        System.out.println(p.depth(t));     
        Node n = new Node();
        n.l = t;
        n.r = e;
        System.out.println(p.depth(n));
    }

    int depth(Tree tree) {
        if(tree instanceof Leaf){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;    
    }

    int depth(Node node) {
        return 1 + Math.max(depth(node.l), depth(node.r));  
    }   

}
    }
```

Good luck!