# Java passing Comparator to constructor

Tags: java, generics, constructor, comparator

If I want to pass to a constructor a Comparator that can compare on two different types, should the parameter of the constructor be like this?:

```
public MyClass(Comparator<?> comp) {
  this.comp = comp;
}
```

Then my comparator class:

```
public NameComparator implements Comparator<String> {

  @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

Then whenever I instantiate the class I do:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(new NameComparator());
```

Is this the correct way to go about doing this?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here's the relevant code:

```
public class BST<T> {
  /* binary search tree */
  ...
  private Comparator<T> c;

  /* pass in comparator to constructor*/
  public BST(Comparator<T> c) {
    this.c = c;
  }
```

Comparator:

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<String> {
 @Override
 public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
   return s2.compareTo(s1);
 }
}
```

When I am creating BST:

```
BST bst = new BST(new NameComparator());
```

Comment: You shouldn't be able to invoke the `compare` method on `this.comp`, because of its wildcard type.

Comment: I'm gonna add more later, but that's not the point of this question. I really wanted to know how to take care of generic types of the constructor

Comment: @Andy Turner then how would I be able to pass in a comparator of different types and perform different compare operations?

Comment: From what you have here, yes; this is the right general approach. But there's not much specific help we can give without specific information.

Comment: You could make the class itself generic: `MyClass<T>` and then only let the constructor accept comparators of the same type (`public MyClass(Comparator<T> comp)`).

Comment: @MickMnemonic I want the constructor to accept only two types: `String` and another custom class I created. How do I do that?

Comment: @Kingamere you would need a type variable declared on the class (e.g. `MyClass<T>`), which you use in the field and parameter type declarations (e.g. `Comparator<T>` or, if you want to be a bit more generic, `Comparator<? super T>`).

Comment: You'd need your "custom class" to implement an interface because Java doesn't have multiple inheritance.

Comment: I did what you said and now I'm getting the error: `The method compare(T, T) in the type Comparator<T> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)`

Comment: @Kingamere please provide that code, you're doing something wrong there.

Comment: @LouisWasserman please check edit in question

Comment: You're creating the BST wrong; it should be `BST<String> bst = new BST<String>(new NameComparator());`

Comment: @LouisWasserman ok that's a different error that I can fix easily, but I'm encountering the above error in the BST class itself where I do this: `...this.c.compare("c", "b") < 0...`. I'm just trying to compare Strings to see if it recognizes, and as Andy Turner said above "You shouldn't be able to invoke the compare method on this.comp, because of its wildcard type". So that's the problem

Comment: @Kingamere, how is a `Comparator` of something other than strings supposed to compare two strings?  You've already stated that your `BST` should work on at least one class that isn't `String`, so how is that supposed to compare `"c"` and `"b"`?

Comment: If you want to support you custom type also, you could do it like this (even though you get a compiler warning because `String` is `final`): `MyClass<T extends String & MyCustomInterface>`, but then the comparator needs to be able to handle both strings and your custom class as Louis mentioned.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I want it compare my custom type including strings. I will try Mick's suggestion below

Comment: @MickMnemonic, that doesn't work even a little bit.  That works for things that are _both_ `String` and `MyCustomInterface`, not one _or_ the other.  @Kingamere, it sounds like you need _two_ comparators, one for strings and one for your other class.  You can't have a `Comparator` that will compare both.

Comment: @MickMnemonic you're saying your suggestion to do `MyClass<T extends String & MyCustomInterface>` won't work?

Comment: @Louis, correct you are. The compiler warning is there _for an obvious reason_; such a `T` cannot exist. :)

Comment: @LouisWasserman You're not understanding my problem. I DO in fact have a comparator for both, what I want to do is have one constructor in a class, that can accept BOTH comparators. I want my binary search tree's constructor to accept both comparators: String type AND my custom class type

Comment: @Kingamere then you need `public class BST { public BST(Comparator<String> stringComparator, Comparator<MyCustomClass> myCustomClassComparator) { ... } }`

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sorry I meant to say, I want the constructor to accept EITHER OR, not BOTH.

Comment: You could make those comparators implement a common marker interface, but anyways the design seems a bit flawed..

Comment: Then you're out of luck, if your goal is a _constructor._  Your only alternative is to use factory methods: `public class BST<T> { private BST(Comparator<T> cmp) { ... } public static BST<String> stringBST() { return new BST<String>(stringComparator); } public static BST<MyType> myTypeBST() { return new BST<MyType>(myTypeComparator); } }`  That is as good as you'll be able to get.  (And a `BST<MyType>` will _still_ not be able to write `comparator.compare("b", "c")`.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman that's quite odd. Then how does Java's `TreeMap` class accept any type of comparator? Says in spec: "The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a **Comparator provided at map creation time**..." I intent to replicate that. I thought it would be much easier.

Comment: @Kingamere you don't need to _restrict_ it to a `String` or your type?  Then you're back to the class you already have that you've edited into the question, where you can choose what type goes into the BST and what type you need to be able to compare.  But you can't guarantee that that type is `String` and you can't just call `this.c.compare("c", "b")` when this might _not_ be a BST for strings.

Comment: *"Then how does Java's TreeMap class accept any type of comparator?"* - It doesn't.  It accepts any comparator of a specific type (depending on `<T>`).  Not a comparator that could be one of two *different* specific types.  Java does not support the kind of typing that you want.

Comment: @Stephen C makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements seem a bit special and you cannot make use of generic types, because `String` is a final class, which your "special class" cannot extend.

You could perhaps make this work by using a *marker interface*, which both of your `Comparator` classes need to implement:

```
/** Marker interface for special comparators */
public interface SpecialComparator{}

public class NameComparator implements Comparator<String>, SpecialComparator{
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
      return s2.compareTo(s1);
    }
}

public class BST {
    /* binary search tree */
    ...
    private SpecialComparator c;

    /* pass in comparator to constructor*/
    public BST(SpecialComparator c) {
      this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this actually accomplishing, then?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, type safety, which is what marker interfaces accomplish, in general (see also Effective Java, Item 37). If you come up with a better suggestion given the constraints, feel free to share your answer.

Comment: Fine, would it be easier to have the constructor accept one Comparator of ANY type, instead of just restricting it to `String` and my "special type" ?

Comment: No, if your code is only designed to work with these two types of comparators.

Comment: @MickMnemonic, eh?  Yes, it's easier _not_ to restrict which types you accept; then you don't have to resort to marker interfaces and the code the OP already has in the original question is correct.

Comment: @LouisWasserman then please tell me, what do I pass into the `compare()` method when I invoke `c.compare`? Because trying `c.compare("s1", "s2")` is giving me that error.

Comment: @LouisWasserman what do I pass as the arguments to `compare`?

Comment: what are you _trying_ to compare?  Why are you trying to compare them?  You can write `BST<String> bst = new BST<String>(new NameComparator()); bst.c.compare("s1", "s2")`, if you like, but you should only be comparing things that are supposed to go into that kind of BST.  You're writing `c.compare("s1", "s2")` when `c` might be a `Comparator<MyClass>`, and that makes no sense.

Comment: The `compare` method is inside the BST class. For adding elements to the tree, I am comparing the value of the data on each node, to the data element being added, and then inserting the data element in the appropriate node. At this point, I think it might just be easier to have two different BST classes: One that accepts comparators of only `String` and the other for my "special class".

Comment: @Kingamere, is that BST for the "special class" going to have `compare("s1", "s2")` in it?  That's the part that doesn't make sense.  Comparing the value of the data on each note to the data element being added makes sense, and _both of those things_ should be of type `T`.  It sounds like you haven't provided us enough of your code to help you resolve that issue.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Ok I see what you are saying. I will read more on generics to clear things up and try to change those objects to type `T`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: A cleaner approach would be to define an `Either<L,R>` class (there are a few patterns for doing that, none of them super elegant in Java ;) ) and use a `Comparator<Either<L,R>>`

Comment: @yshavit, you're right (at least about the [Java solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975836/how-can-i-simulate-haskells-either-a-b-in-java) not being very elegant) :)